# How to list double entries of the concatenation of two columns?

Tags: postgresql

How to list the double entries of the *concatenation* of two columns ?

Currently, I'm using this query to list doubles in a single column:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(col_a) AS count,
    col_a
FROM mytable
GROUP BY col_a
HAVING COUNT(col_a) > 1
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: Replace `col_a` with `col_a || col_b`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It works perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2f6643e8cc57c35c5cd19cd4d6d4973d)

First concatenate them and do your operation afterwards:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(concat) AS count,
    concat
FROM (
    SELECT col_a || col_b AS concat FROM t
) s
GROUP BY concat
HAVING COUNT(concat) > 1
ORDER BY count DESC
```